# How to write a JavaScript plugin in the Pro/Ninja Way?

Tags: javascript

I don't need advice about the JavaScript code but about the files organization. I mean, I could write all my jedi code in a single `.js` file but I know it won't be the very best way to do it. So, this is a standard way to do this or it's all about free will?

By the way, I'll host it in github, in case there's a thing as "the github way for organizing a JavaScript plugin files".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no well-defined standards on how you split up your files. It is more about how well your JavaScript code is organized.

I would split it up in a way that makes sense to you, and if you are worried about end users having to load multiple files then there are ways of combining them into one for the release.